# Pentaho CDE : Provide different datasources for each bar of stacked bar chart

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-cde

I am using pentaho CDE.

Is there a way, that I can provide a different datasource (MySQL query) for each bar of a CCC stacked bar chart ?

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar : I had a chart with a "dummy" datasource jsonscriptable over scripting and a function that, via ajax , activated different queries within a promise for building a resultset. Then, in the postfetch of the chart, I just returned the built resultset.

**Edit**

So assume I have the dashboard testpromise in /home/myhome with 3 datasources returning a similar resultset (that is : the same number of columns with the same types). 
In my dashboard, I have in fact the same query invoked 3 times with different parameters : you will have to adjust the code. Let's say that our chart is named mychart.
 I have a button (but it can be anything else) with the following code on click action :

```
    function(){

 Dashboards.res=[];//will contain the result ; As for Pentaho 5.4 without RequireJS, Dashboards is a global varialbe, so that Dashboards.res is accessible eveywhere
 Promise.all([getib3(2016,3),getib3(2015,3),getib3(2016,8)]).then(
     function(r){
//res contains the result of the 3 queries
       console.log(res);
       Dashboards.etComponentByName('render_mychart').update(); //Activates the chart
    },
    function(err) { 
        console.error(err);
    }     
);
function getib3(a,m){
          var postquery='path=%2Fhome%2myhome%Ftestpromise.cda&dataAccessId=sql_get_ib3&paramparam_annee='+a+'&paramparam_mois=' +m;
        $.ajax({
                        url:  '/pentaho/plugin/cda/api/doQuery?',
                        type: 'POST',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        data: postquery,
                       // async:false,
                     }).done(function (data) {   console.log(data)  ;
                           res.push(data.resultset);//ad the result of the query

                        }).fail(function ( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert('query :' + textStatus);
                        });
}
}
```

The chart is associated with a dummy jsonscript datasource  its property "execute at start" is set to false . The postfetch property  :

```
function(d) {//d is the resultset of the dummy datasource, here we can ignore it.
       return (Dashboards.res); //We override d with the resultset we build above
}
```

Have fun!

Comment: can you attach that ajax function, and post fetch code here.

Comment: yes, I must find where the code is... I'll post it tomorrow

Comment: How & where is this feeding each bar of the chart with a different datasource ?

Comment: You have to configure your chart by defining the series, the axis and so on. Then, the  postfech property of the chart does the job of feeding it with the data